# AWS Sagemaker - Blazingtext BatchTransform no output

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I have trained a blazingText model and followed this guide.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/blazingtext.html

"Sample JSON request" The Invoke end point is working perfectly. So I switched to,
Batch Transform Job with "content-type: application/jsonlines" and created a file in S3 with the following format data:

```
{"source": "source_0"}
```

The job ran success. But the output did not sent to S3. Also In the cloud logs,

```
" [79] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 79"
```

This is is the last response. Did anyone know what went wrong?

Comment: Can you share your code for creating the `Transformer` object and the `transform()` function? I'm trying something similar, but it's giving me an "Incorrect Payload Format" error. Do you have anything in the JSON file apart from "source"? Any ID or label, maybe?

Comment: Can you share yours ? I can debug easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue. The batchtransform select the folder as input and the s3 source should be S3Prefix instead of manifest.